# opencv_createsamples creates invalid syntax

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'm working on this tutorial here: https://pythonprogramming.net/haar-cascade-object-detection-python-opencv-tutorial/

With a little bit of adaption from python 2.X to 3.6, I managed to get everything working till a certain part:

Using opencv_createsamples

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.492]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

C:\Users\azach>python
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit 
(AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
import os
os.getcwd()
'C:\\Users\\azach'
path = 'C:\\Users\\azach\\Desktop\\python\\haar'
import cv2
os.chdir(path)
opencv_createsamples -info /pos.lst -num 2500 -w 20 -h 20 -vec pos.vec
 File "<stdin>", line 1
 opencv_createsamples -info /pos.lst -num 2500 -w 20 -h 20 -vec pos.vec
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

SyntaxError marks the "." of pos.lst, which is my datalist with information on positive images.

As requested here are a few lines of pos.lst

```
 pos/Download (1).jpg 1 0 0 400 400
 pos/Download (10).jpg 1 0 0 400 400
 pos/Download (2).jpg 1 0 0 400 400
```

All of these images exist.

Comment: where is pos.lst on your disk (absolute path?) anf what is your working directory?

Comment: I set my working directory with os.chdir to this 'C:\\Users\\azach\\Desktop\\python\\haar' . This is also the folder pos.lst is located.

Comment: try removing the slash before the filename or use a ./ instead

Comment: I tried both and I still receive the same error

Comment: can you post some lines of that pos.lst file? Did you try to reduce the pos file to a single line and make sure that image exists? Did you make sure there is no empty line at the end of the file?

Comment: I'll added a few lines from pos.lst to OP

Comment: probably filenames with white spaces aren't allowed. You can try to use " but probably you'll have to rename all your files. try to verify with a few single lines until it works and ajust your whole file list...

Comment: Change it to single line "pos/test.jpg 1 0 0 400 400" and created the picture test.jpg. But there is still the same.

Comment: sorry, no more idea then

Comment: nethertheless thank you very much!

Comment: http://answers.opencv.org/question/136730/createsamples-throws-invalid-syntax-error-following-documentation/

Where's your opencv_createsamples application located? Does python interpret the command line parameters as individual applications?

Comment: I also found that post: 
C:\\Users\\azach\\Downloads\\opencv\\build\\x64\\vc15\\bin\\opencv_createsample.exe"
I'm not sure about your second question.